# Making the log.html more verbose when using the API

Tags: python, logging, robotframework

I am attempting to use the API for building and running test suites and I've noticed that the log.html that is output when using the API vs the shell is subtly different.

[image: The log when using the command line invocation]

The log when using the command line invocation

[image: The log when run through a minimal python script]

The log when run through a minimal python script

The minimal python script:

```
import robot.api
import robot.result
from robot.conf.settings import RobotSettings

options = {
    "output": "./results.xml",
    "log": "./log.html",
    "report": "./report.html",
    "loglevel": "TRACE"
}

settings = RobotSettings(options)

suite = robot.api.TestSuiteBuilder().build(".")
result = suite.run(settings=settings)

result_writer = robot.api.ResultWriter(result)
result_writer.write_results(settings=settings.get_rebot_settings())
```

As can be seen the log is missing a lot of keyword detail, how can I get this back?

edit: The minimal file after changing it to the correct method:

```
import robot.api
import robot.result
from robot.conf.settings import RobotSettings

options = {
    "output": "./results.xml",
    "log": "./log.html",
    "report": "./report.html",
    "loglevel": "TRACE",
    "rpa": False
}

settings = RobotSettings(options)

suite = robot.api.TestSuiteBuilder().build(".")
result = suite.run(settings=settings)

result_writer = robot.api.ResultWriter("./results.xml")
result_writer.write_results(settings=settings.get_rebot_settings())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have two different `Robot Framework` packages active on your system? One externally in your path and another as a package within your `venv`.
Try

```
robot --version
```

and check if the version in your `cmd` line is the same as the one running the script.
You should also try to upgrade to the latest version, which typically solves such errors.

I have also found a similar error [on this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotframework-users/VJvOCLoVuzc), which states

> The problem is that the result object you get from
> `suite.run(settings)` doesn't contain all information about test
> execution. The reason for this behavior is saving memory during test
> execution. All information about the execution is in the generated
> output.xml file, and what you need to do is passing a path to it to
> the `ResultWriter` class instead of the result object. This ought to
> be documented somewhere in the API docs but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: I only ever ran anything inside a venv so it was never going to be the former, but the quote from the newsgroup was exactly what was wrong. I've since searched the documentation and can't find any reference to this drawback.